# Font embedding with css

Tags: css, fonts

I am trying to import a font using the CSS below, it works in Firefox, and IE, but not in Chrome is not supporting. Can you help me on making it work in Chrome too?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fontin-Bold";
    src: url(fonts/Fontin-Bold.ttf);
    src: url(fonts/Fontin-Bold.eot);
}
```

Comment: Do you see some error, using the developer tool, when viewing the page with Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers have different needs, and fonts are no exception. Here's a full example:

**CSS**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'UbuntuBold';
    src: url('ubuntu-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('ubuntu-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('ubuntu-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('ubuntu-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('ubuntu-bold-webfont.svg#UbuntuBold') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}
```

You are better of using a Font-Face Generator like: [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator)

Additionally, you need to set an **.htaccess** on your fonts folder with the following types:

```
AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/otf .otf
```

---

**EDITED:**

To better explain the **different font formats** *VS* **different browsers**:

- Firefox and Safari support TTF or OTF format;
- Internet Explorer supports EOT format;
- Firefox 3.6 supports the new WOFF (new format proposal for a web font
  file);
- Google Chrome, and iPhone’s Safari allow to use SVG files in
  @font-face;

Comment: Very useful answer, but what's the part specifically inherent to Chrome?

Comment: @Carlo, just added an edited section with a more specific font type for each browser...